# how to submit a form using jquery in jsp

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jsp, post

In ASP.net MVC using the following snippet we can send the change password data to a controller. In the controller we can cast the posted data as ChangepasswordReq object and we can do our business. Now I am looking for the equivalent of this in **jsp**. How to communicate from the client side to the server side? I want to transfer a bigger form with number of controls.(I am using only html to build my pages). Any Help would be appreciable.

```
 var ChangeReq = { CurrentPassword: epwd, NewPassword: newpwd }
 var jsondata = JSON.stringify(ChangeReq)

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "/Account/ChangePassword",
                cache: false,
                timeout: 10000,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (_results) {
                    //do something

                },
                error: function (_results) {
                   //do something
                }
            });


  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult ChangePassword(ChangepasswordReq _ChangepasswordReq)
  {
     //do the business
  }

  public class ChangepasswordReq
    {
        public String CurrentPassword { get; set; }
        public String NewPassword { get; set; }
    }
```

---

I have tried the following. But in my case I am generating some controls dynamically. I cannot get them properly in the controller as the number of dynamic controls vary. Is there any better way in jsp for the url routing as in asp.net MVC.(better than **@RequestMapping(value = "/ChangePassword", method = RequestMethod.POST**))
How to use jquery properly in jsp.(Please help me in client side and server side code)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ChangePassword", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String home(@RequestParam("Currentpasswordtxtboxname") String Currentpassword,@RequestParam("NewPasswordtextboxname") String Newpassword, Locale locale, Model model) {
// do business
}
```

Comment: Time permitting, take a glance on how to format your posts: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: communicating from client to server will be the same regardless of whether its JSP, ASP.NET, PHP etc. The client POSTs to a URL, and in JSP you handle the POST variables. 

I think you're asking about what to do on the server, not the client  as you stated. Your post is not clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found something [Here](http://www.programming-free.com/2012/09/ajax-with-servlets-using-jquery-and-json.html?showComment=1350468049308#c5285910718433761568).

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    function Savedata() {  
    Var data={Username:$("#txtUsername").[0].value, CurrentPassword:  $("#txtCurrentpwd").[0].value, NewPassword: $("#txtNewpwd").[0].value }

   jsondata=Json.stringify(data);
   $.get('ActionServlet',jsondata,function(responseJson) {   
        //do something with response json
        });
    });
});         
 //Can use Jquery post also as in question
</script>
```

In the server side we can get the parameters as

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
 {
  String Username =request.getParameter("Username");
  String CurrentPwd =request.getParameter("CurrentPassword");
  String Newpwd =request.getParameter("NewPassword");
 }
```

In the web.xml file

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>ActionServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>MyProject.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>ActionServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/ActionServlet/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery is equal for sending to jsp, asp or php, the server side is who changes. Maybe the correct answer is how to recib data in jsp.

Comment: I know about that.. what will be the efficient way for accepting the data in server side in jsp from a jquery post.